# Is it safe to unescape ampersand for user input?

Tags: php, html, html-entities, sanitization

After a few hours of bug searching, I found out the cause of one of my most annoying bugs.

When users are typing out a message on my site, they can title it with plaintext and html entities.

This means in some instances, users will type a title with common html entity pictures like this face. ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°).

To prevent html injection, I use htmlspecialchars(); on the title, and annoyingly it would convert the picture its html entity format when outputted onto the page later on.

```
( &#865;° &#860;&#662; &#865;°)
```

I realized the problem here was that the title was being encoded as the example above, and htmlspecialchar, as well as doing what I wanted and encoding possible html injection, was turning the ampersand in the entities to

```
&amp;.
```

By un-escaping all the ampersands, and changing them back to & this fixed my problem and the face would come out as expected.

However I am unsure if this is still safe from malicious html. Is it safe to decode the ampersands in user imputed titles? If not, how can I go about fixing this issue?

Comment: If your entities are displayed as text, then you're probably calling `htmlspecialchars()` twice.

Comment: @Marat. When the POST was grabbing the value from the input, it would auto encode the more obscure entities like the nose and mouth of the face I provided. However it did NOT encode things like quotes or the pointed brackets. So that is indeed my problem, some of the entities are getting encoded twice. Unfortunately I do not know how to go about fixing this, other than encoding once again. This is why I have asked the question, to see if there is a better way.

Comment: Such browser-side auto-escaping may occur if the page containing the form is using an obsolete single-byte encoding like Windows-1252. Are you sure you're using Unicode (UTF-8 in particular)? ;-)

Comment: I am not sure. This is one of my first projects dealing with html entities, and I do not know much about this. How would I switch over to using unicode?

Comment: Clint, please see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your entities are displayed as text, then you're probably calling `htmlspecialchars()` twice.

If you are not calling `htmlspecialchars()` twice explicitly, then it's probably a browser-side auto-escaping that may occur if the page containing the form is using an obsolete single-byte encoding like Windows-1252. Such automatic escaping is the only way to correctly represent characters not present in character set of the specific single-byte encoding. All current browsers (including Firefox, Opera, and IE) do this.

Make sure you are using Unicode (UTF-8 in particular) encoding.

To use Unicode as encoding, add the `<meta charset="utf-8" />` element to the `HEAD` section of the HTML page that contains the form. And don't forget to save the HTML page itself in UTF-8 encoding. To use Unicode in PHP, it's typically enough to use [multibyte (`mb_` prefixed) string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php). Finally, database engines like MySQL do support UTF-8 long ago.

As a temporary workaround, you can disable reencoding existing entities by setting 4th parameter (`$double_encode`) of the [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function to `false`.

Comment: Thank you! The work around of adding false worked perfectly. I will look into UTF-8. I read on some other forums that it isnt necessary and takes a lot of work to implement it, and sometimes it isnt worth the time.

In your opinion, is it worth switching over?

Comment: @Clint Actually, it's not that hard to use UTF-8 (in PHP, see [`mb_` prefixed functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php)). Try it and you'll like it. ;-)

Comment: +1 to Marat for noting the encoding could be the problem (you can also get the same into databases and be careful of JSON - encoding is a minefield). RE: "Is it worth switching over"? - Marat's said the setting 4th parameter of htmlspecialchars is a "temporary solution" and I agree that it really is a cop-out. You'll dig yourself into a deeper hole unless you find the source. So do check for the character set (as Marat said) or check for the code doing the encoding - it really is worth fixing and keeping track of what variables are encoded and what aren't IMO.

Answer (score 3):

There is no straight answer. You may unesacape `&lt;script...&gt;` into `<script...>` and end in trouble, however it looks like the code has been double encoded - probably once on input and then again when you output to screen. If you can guarantee it has been double encoded, then it should be safe to undo one of those.

However, the best solution is to keep the "raw" value in memory, and sanitize/encode for outputting into databases, html, JSON etc.

So - when you get input, sanitise it for anything you don't want, but don't actually convert it into HTML or escape it or anything else at this stage. Escape it into a database, html encode it when output to screen / xml etc.

Comment: That is what I believe is happening. When I gather the input value from POST the more obscure entities are already being encoded automatically (I am not too experienced with php, and do not know why), however the common entities such as &, <  and > are being left decoded. This is why I am double encoding. Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Remove the initial encoding. You'll need to find out where it's happening.

Comment: Based on another comment, I believe it is the browser auto-escaping the value in the input. How can I remove that?

Comment: Browser won't do that. JavaScript might - so if the data is submitted handled by JavaScript then check in there for that. Otherwise it'll be inside the PHP code. Look for "htmlspecialchars", "hemlentities" or "preg_replace" calls in the php code.